# Как увеличить высоту комбобокса?

Tags: delphi

Добрый день! Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно увеличить высоту комбобокса? Нормальными средствами не получается (изменяя св-во Height).

Comment: шрифт поменять?

Comment: То есть ИтемВысоту.(itemHeight)

Comment: Спасибо, Yura Ivanov, Vfvtnjd, выручили! Работает и так и так. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Style:=csOwnerDrawFixed;

Потом height задаете....